# could not open grads on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, lubuntu, 22.10

I installed grads on Ubuntu 22.10 by using sudo apt-get install grads:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
grads is already the newest version (3:2.2.1-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.

I also checked the path:
which grads

/usr/bin/grads

and when I type grads in terminal it could not open and say:

grads: symbol lookup error:
grads: undefined symbol: _ZN6libdap3DDS7var_endEv

Do you know what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apt-file` utility to examine which files have been installed by a package. apt-file is not installed by default but is available in the standard repos.

```
apt-file list grads
...
grads: /usr/bin/bufrscan                  
grads: /usr/bin/grads
grads: /usr/bin/grib2scan
grads: /usr/bin/gribmap
grads: /usr/bin/gribscan
grads: /usr/bin/stnmap
...
```

I've only included /usr/bin files in the redacted output as these are the main binaries that are made available by the grads package. Might be worth reading the man page for any that look like they are what you need or, alternatively, refer to the grads online documentation.